# PlaySound does not work

Tags: c++, windows, audio, glut

I have a tetris game and I want to add a background music to it.
I am trying to use `PlaySound(TEXT("Tetris.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);` but instead of music, I just get "windows sound".

It compiles. I guess it does not want to work with glut.

Here's my `main()`

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("Tetris.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(1000, 10);
    glutCreateWindow("Tetris");
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 150, 200, 0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    timer(0);
    glutSpecialFunc(keyEvent);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

I have `#include <Windows.h>` and `#include <MMSystem.h.>` included and it works fine here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <MMSystem.h.>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    PlaySound(TEXT("Tetris.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So is it because of glut and can I fix it somehow?

Comment: As written, your program is looking for the file "Tetris.wav" in the **current directory**.  Do you know which directory that is?  Do you know how to check?

Comment: @DrewDormann Tetris.wav in the same folder as my project.

Comment: Try using the full path to be certain the directory isn't the issue.

Comment: @MrEricSir nope, still nothing

Comment: I suppose you have read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx)? `SND_FILENAME`?

Comment: In particular: "*If the file cannot be found, **the function plays the default sound** unless the SND_NODEFAULT flag is set.*" ALWAYS use an absolute path, and if the system is still not able to find the file, then use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see exactly where the system is actually looking for the file

Answer (score 2):

First, you'd better use an absolute path.

Second, I would use the `SND_FILENAME` flag, as described by [the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx).

(I cannot imagine this having anything to do with GLUT.)

Comment: Third, I would use `SND_ASYNC`, since the file is meant to be used as *background music*. If you use `SND_SYNC`, `PlaySound()` will not exit until the entire WAV file is played. `SND_ASYNC` will queue up the audio and then exit immediately so it can continue playing in the background.

Comment: Also, even though using `SND_FILENAME` is preferred, it is also optional in this case: "*Three flags in fdwSound (SND_ALIAS, SND_FILENAME, and SND_RESOURCE) determine whether the name is interpreted as an alias for a system event, a file name, or a resource identifier. If none of these flags are specified, PlaySound searches the registry or the WIN.INI file for an association with the specified sound name. If an association is found, the sound event is played. **If no association is found in the registry, the name is interpreted as a file name**.*"